# I unplugged a flash drive before a file was flushed to it. Can I recover that file somehow?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, sublime-text-3

Using Sublime Text 3, I saved a file to my flash drive and unplugged it immediately (without safely removing). Unfortunately, the file was not stored on the flash drive, so I must have unplugged it before the buffer was flushed to the medium. The file isn't saved anywhere else.

The Session.sublime_session file has an entry for the file (including the location I saved it on the flash drive), but no associated buffer/content.

How might I recover this file?

Comment: "sublime_session file has an entry for the file, ..., but no associated buffer/content." - You have answered your own question.  The content does not exist on the PC used to create the file

Comment: My hope is that there is some way to access the buffer that windows uses to store that data before flushing it.

Comment: The buffer does not exist per your own description of the situation.  Be more careful in the future, or save files locally, and then transfer them to your removable storage.

Comment: The document should remain in sublime unless you worked on it whilst it was on the USB key, or closed the document.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I closed sublime text (the whole window) after unplugging the flash drive, and when I reopened it, the file was empty.